# How to solve java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError error? Where can I found the right JRE version?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-11, java-17

I am working on a Java application (a Spring Boot application). On my Ubuntu development machine I have used this JDK version:

```
andrea@ubuntu:~$ java --version
java 17 2021-09-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17+35-LTS-2724)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17+35-LTS-2724, mixed mode, sharing)
```

This is the **pom.xml** file of my Spring Boot application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.notariato</groupId>
    <artifactId>UpdateInfoBatch</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>UpdateInfoBatch</name>
    <description>Recupera ed aggiorna le informazioni relative alla lista dei notai ed ai distretti notarili</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    

    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
    
    
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I obtained the **.jar** application and I have no problem running it on my development machine.

The problem happened when I tried to move this **.jar** file on the production machine.

Here the Java version is the following one:

```
webadmin@webadmin.spaccount.it [~/java/jre1.8.0_311/bin]# ./java -version
java version "1.8.0_311"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_311-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.311-b11, mixed mode)
webadmin@webadmin.spaccount.it [~/java/jre1.8.0_311/bin]#
```

So, as you can see, here the JAVA version seems to be the **1.8.0_311**

Running my application I obtained this error message:

```
webadmin@webadmin.spaccount.it [~/java/jre1.8.0_311/bin]# ./java -jar /home/webadmin/notartel-import-data-batch/UpdateInfoBatch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/notariato/updateInfo/UpdateInfoBatchApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
```

It seems that the installed JRE is too old. I was trying to manually download the JRE package for JAVA 17 but I cannot find it.

What version of the JRE have I to use? Where can I download this JRE package version? (not with the yum package manager, I need to download the tar file containing the JRE and then extract it on my system).

Thank you

Comment: Which OS are you using on your server? Which JDK distribution do you want to use? In case you want to use Adoptium Temurin you can download it from the official website: https://adoptium.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk17&jvmVariant=hotspot In case you are using Linux, you might want to check the package manager of your distribution, first. Or you might want to take a look at SDKMAN: https://sdkman.io/

Comment: With java 17 consider packaging a JRE with your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traditional JREs no longer exist since Java 9 (although some vendors offer JRE-like packages). In order to get a Java runtime to run your application you can use the [`jlink`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/jlink.html) tool, which also comes with JDK 17, like this for a **modular** application:

```
jlink -p <directory app jar> --add-modules <name of your module> --output custom_runtime
```

If your application is **non-modular**, you will have to find out which modules you need, for instance using [`jdeps`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/jdeps.html) (also a tool that comes with JDK 17):

```
$ mvn dependency:build-classpath -DincludeScope=runtime -Dmdep.outputFile=cp.txt
$ jdeps -classpath "<contents of cp.txt>" --multi-release 17 --print-module-deps --ignore-missing-deps <app jar>
```

Which prints something like `mod1,mod2,mod3`. Pass them to the `--add-modules` flag instead:

```
jlink --add-modules mod1,mod2,mod3 --output custom_runtime
```

This will generate a `custom_runtime` folder with a Java runtime you can use to run your app, which can then be deployed on the target machine.

If your app is **non-modular** you will also have to deploy the app `.jar` file, and all of it's dependencies (there should be no external runtime dependencies for a Spring Boot project, since it bundles all dependencies in the app jar). Then, use the `java` executable in the custom runtime to run the app:

```
/path/to/custom/runtime/java -jar <app jar>
```